# Filtering years on excel dataset in python

Tags: python, linear-regression

How can I filter by year in Python? I want to pick the last 20 years from an excel. The columns are just *date* and *price*.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv') start_date="2000-01-01", end_date="2020-01-01")
```

I was expecting to get the last 20 years from the data.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! You might want to look over how to write a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask here, and include some code and what you've currently tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try one of these 2 approach:

Approach 1:

```py
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[(df['date']>datetime.date(2000,1,1)) and (df['date']<datetime.date(2020,1,1))]
```

Approach 2:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[(df['date']>"2000-01-01" and df['date']<"2020-01-01")]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried the 2nd option, I still got this error

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-cce232aa93b7> in <module>
----> 1 df = df[(df['Date']>"2000-01-01" & df['Date']<"2019-01-01")]

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/roperator.py in rand_(left, right)
     50 
     51 def rand_(left, right):
---> 52     return operator.and_(right, left)
     53 
     54 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'DatetimeArray'

Comment: My mistake. Just replace the & with the word 'and'. I also edited my answer to show the change.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution. I appreciate